# JobTracker UI not showing progress of hadoop job

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, mahout, jobs

I am testing my MR jobs under a single node cluster.
Once I installed mahout 9 version Mapreduce jobs stopped showing the progress in jobtracker.(Dont know if that happened after mahout installation)

When ever I run a job in my hadoop cluster it wont show the status in job tacker UI as previous and the execution log displaying in the console is also different (similar to mahout logs)

Why is it so?

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Can you add a snippet of error log here?

Comment: @RamananR: There is no error logs or anything . My MapReduce jobs are executing fine. But I am not able to see its progress in Jobtracker UI after installing mahout(assumption..Dnt know if that happened after mahout installation)

Answer (score 2):

Most probably you job might be running using [LocalJobRunner](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/LocalJobRunner.html). If your job is using `LocalJobRunner` you'll notice `mapred.LocalJobRunner` events in the mapreduce job output. This could of couple of reasons:

**In case of MapReduce v1**:

Make sure your `mapred-site.xml` has the property `mapred.job.tracker` and is pointing to appropriate JobTracker host and port:

```
<property>  
  <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>  
  <value>[fqdn_of_jobtracker]:[port_of_jobtracker]</value>  
</property>
```

Generally, LocalJobRunner will be choosen by the mapreduce if the hadoop cannot read the property `mapreduce.framework.name` or if the property has been set to `local`.

If this does not pan out then try explicitly specifying the property using hadoop's generic command line option like:

```
hadoop jar hadoop-examples.jar pi -jt [fqdn_of_jt]:[port_of_jt] 2 1000
```

**In case of YARN and MapReduce v2**:

If you are running MapReduce on top of YARN in that case, the job would be run by `LocalJobRunner` if you haven't specified the mapreduce framework name in `mapred-site.xml`, so make sure you have the following property:

```
<property>  
  <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>  
  <value>yarn</value>  
</property>
```